# How to send SMS that will pop up on screen in Android?

Tags: android, sms, alert

Is it possible to do this, when I send a SMS, it will pop-up/prompt on screen so that it will easily alert the receiver using this.

Comment: you mean you want to show an alert when there is an outgoing sms ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following customized method to send SMS,

```
public static void sendsms( String address,String msgContent )
{
    try
    {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> smsString = sms.divideMessage(msgContent); 
        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(address, null, smsString, null, null);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and use following code to display AlertDialog,

```
// Sending SMS 
sendSMS ( "9898989898","hello this is sms" );

// showing alertdialog
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle( "SMS" );
alertDialog.setMessage( "Sending SMS" );
alertDialog.setButton( "OK", getDialogListener());
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: I mean Sir, the content of the text message will pop up on screen of the receiver's phone just like a flash message. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, that is also possible, but you need to wait again, i will write that code,

Answer (score -1):

You can use a broadcast receiver and display a notification when a new message is arrived.